# Unable to get remote ip and location on liferay porlets

Tags: geolocation, ip, liferay, portlet

I am using ubuntu 12.04, liferay version 6.0.1, open jdk 6 on my system. I was trying to get remote ip and location in java. For this I have found [Host Ip](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) service by which using apache http get method we can get the location. I have executed this successfully on my local system. But On the actual server the liferay portlet is not running and its hard to find the error as multiple instances are running at the same time. The server is a Window based.
I am using this method in a doView() of a MVC Portlet to get ip

```
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getRemoteAddr()
```

Comment: `getRemoteAddr` gives you Domain IP and not individual system IP , in your case when you are running multiple Liferay instances and is made available in Internet. If you are using Load Balancer, you ll get your Load Balancer IP and not individual system IP.

Comment: So how could I get the Ip and location of the remote user accessing my site?

Comment: Have a look at this (post)[http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1205166]. Am not sure if that guy got System IP of Domain IP

Comment: There is nothing valuable in the link. please give some accurate information.

Comment: there's a superfluous ] ending that link. Try https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1205166 - related: Do you have an Apache as frontend for your production server? It might be the address of that which you get as remote address (especially if you proxy through http)

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock But unfortunately in the above link iceFaces has been used and I am not using iceFaces, which results in the error during executing the help code. (please excuse me i am a newbie and doesn't know much)

Comment: what about the apache question?

Comment: Yes I am using Apache as Development and as a Production server.

Answer (score 1):

When I wan't to access http header info I use:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest);
HttpServletRequest originalServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpServletRequest);
originalServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
```

Usually you cant find the real header information in the *httpServletRequest* but they are available in the *originalServletRequest*

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer. I do not know the location part of the answer. Hope this helps

Checkout the [MyIP Portlet on Liferay Marketplace](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/23652330) - it does have a util function that does only  part of getting IP address from RenderRequest or PortletRequest object.

You may be interested in looking at the [github source](https://github.com/fromdev/my-ip-portlet) of same at : [IPAddressUtil.java](https://github.com/fromdev/my-ip-portlet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fromdev/portlets/util/IPAddressUtil.java)